# How to remove the content of folders before unzipping many zips? (bash script)

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I have many folders on FTP with their content, and some of them I must update from time to time. I update them by unzipping zip files I receive. Names of zips may be various, but in a zip, there is always the main folder with exactly the same name of a folder that should be updated on FTP. No more other files/folders in zips other than the main folder with its content. So I wrote a simple script below to update them:

```
unzip -o \*.zip
rm -f *.zip
```

The problem is, sometimes there are files that should be deleted in these folders - they no longer exist in zips with updates. And I realized that when I unzip and overwrite, nothing is deleted what should be. Is it possible to modify this script, to remove a whole folder before unzipping to be sure? The proper name of a folder to update is not the name of zip, but the name of the main folder in zip, and because of that I don't know how to solve this. I couldn't find an existing solution for this. Also, sometimes I upload many zips at once, and there are thousands of folders on FTP so it would be hard to write a single command for every single folder.

Comment: Why do you mention FTP. Does FTP play a role in your problem at all or would it be the same problem if you were receiving the zip archives from another source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unzip` companion program `zipinfo` to list the contents of the zip files. Add the pattern `*/` to list only directories. Then pipe to `xargs` to remove them.

```
zipinfo -1 '*.zip' '*/' | xargs rm -rf 2>/dev/null
```

This will remove all existing directories (which match in an existing zip file) at once. You can then run the rest of your script to extract the new ones.

You could add `cut -d / -f 1 | sort -u |`  before `xargs` to filter out any subdirectories for `rm`, but it shouldn't matter even if there are some.

`xargs` splits lines by whitespace, so a directory name containing whitespace could result in a different directory being removed. For GNU `xargs`, you can add `--delimiter='\n'` to stop that (there's also `--null`, but `zip` truncates new lines in file names anyway). You can also just exclude directories containing spaces by piping through `grep -v '[[:space:]]'`.

Another approach which may be useful is to process one zip file at a time:

```
for zip in *.zip; do
    dirs=$(zipinfo -1 "$zip" '*/') || continue
    IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a dirs<<<"$dirs"

    rm -rf "${dirs[@]}"
    unzip -o "$zip"
done
```

This method is also fine with whitespace. Splitting `dirs` in to an array just means `rm` will still succeed if there is more than one directory in an archive. If `zipinfo` fails, it probably means the archive is corrupt or unreadable, hence `|| continue`. You can remove that if you want to attempt extraction regardless.